How to resolve the "error: [MissingType]: Element 'com.example.XXXXDatabase' references a type that is not present"?
I am attempting to implement a Room library in an Android Studio project. However, I keep getting the following error:
[MissingType]: Element 'com.example.XXX.AppDatabase' references a type that is not present
I have come across a similar question (error: [MissingType]: Element 'xxxxx.AppDatabase.room' references a type that is not present), however, after trying all of the suggestions nothing helped. I believe this has something to do with build.gradle file, but I do not know how to fix it.
This is the implementation of my AppDatabase:
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase


@Database(entities = arrayOf(GameReview::class), version = 8)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun gameDao(): GameDao
    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
         // context.deleteDatabase("gamereview")
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(AppDatabase::class) {
                    INSTANCE = buildRoomDB(context)
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
        private fun buildRoomDB(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "gamereview"
            ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()    //fallbackToDestructiveMigration().
    }

and this is my build.gradle(Module:app) file:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.rma23_19084_projekat'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rma23_19084_projekat"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:+'
    testImplementation("org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2")
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.tracing:tracing:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'


    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.5.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:2.5.3")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3")
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:+"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.15.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:+'

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2")
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")


}

I have also implemented entity, dao and a repository for utilising AppDatabase in the Main activity. If it's necessary, I can include these files as well, but I was not sure since this is the first time I am encountering this error and I am not sure what it means.
To anyone answering this, thank you in advance!

Does this answer your question? error: [MissingType]: Element 'xxxxx.AppDatabase.room' references a type that is not present

I tried the methods suggested in this post, but without any success ) : I believe it might be due to build.gradle file, but I am not sure how to fix this.

Sorted out this by https://stackoverflow.com/a/79307696/13651898
